# making a sql populated dropdown duplicate the same using a plus sign button to add another and have the space for it increase dynamically

Tags: html, angular, forms, bootstrap-4, addition

I need to have a plus sign next to this and have it add/remove repeat and the section of the form grow dynamically and decrease dynamically based on which is clicked. I was thinking to turn it into a function but being a new developer I don't quite know how to do that. This is in Angular with a spring backend for the list population

```
<section>
    <br>
    <p>
        <label for="sysapp" class="appRole">System Application
        </label>
        <app-sysapp-list id="sysapp" (selectedSysAppEvent)="updateAppName($event)"></app-      sysapp-list>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="rolename" class="appRole">System Role Name</label>
          
        <app-rolename-list id="rolename" [appName]="appName"></app-rolename-list>
    </p>
</section>
```

I tried adding the add and remove buttons and tried to put it all into a click(). I have seen this is TurboTax where clicking an add or remove button makes the space increase or decrease but I don't know how to turn html code into a function.